# Update Facebook Page Wall via API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook

I am having difficulty both publishing content to a Facebook Page wall, and also finding up to date documentation about how to accomplish this (the Facebook pages that I have found links to in other questions asked here either are missing or broken).

The application I am writing would periodically push content on a schedule basis from a ruby on rails application via a cron job/rake task to the fan page wall. I am hoping that someone may have an up to date guide or instructions on how to push content to Facebook page walls.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Koala rocks my world!

Assuming you have asked for write permission to their wall (first read this: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/ [pay attention to the 'scope' parameter] refer to this for the permissions: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/ [you'll need to ask for publish_stream permisson], then read https://github.com/arsduo/koala/wiki/OAuth), and have a valid oauth token, its as simple as:

```
@graph.put_wall_post("hey, i'm learning koala")
```

https://github.com/arsduo/koala/wiki/Graph-API

Also, read https://github.com/arsduo/koala/wiki/Koala-on-Rails for Koala on ROR.

See the oauth examples at:http://oauth.twoalex.com/ (Source code: https://github.com/arsduo/oauth_playground)